# PHP - function not working when used inside foreach

Tags: php, foreach, switch-statement

I'm doing a loop thro XML and collecting data from it. Some values need to be translated so i've made a switch function, which is wrapped inside another function and called on every loop to check the original value and change it according defined new value within the switch.

The problem is if i include the switch inside the foreach the original value get's changed properly (strings of the original variable $foo are translated). But if i wrap the switch in function and call that function within the loop then the original value doesn't get changed. It needs to be `if ($foo == 'one') $foo == 'ein'`... Here's my code:

```
function checkTranslation($foo) {
    switch($foo) {
        case('one'): $foo = 'ein'; break;
        case('two'): $foo = 'zwei'; break;
        ...
    }
};

foreach ($XML -> some -> data as $item) {
    $foo = $item['value'];
    checkTranslation($foo);
}
```

Comment: You need to `return` from the function and assign it to a variable outside, otherwise it's not visible in the global scope. Alternatively, pass by reference. And as per this code, you're not actually using the `$foo` variable (but I assume that's just cut off for this question?)

Comment: There's a lot going on here.  First, you're not returning anything from your function. Second your function is not acting on $foo, but instead a copy of $foo. Thirdly, you're not assigning the returned value of your function to anything.  Fourthly, if you were, it would be overwritten with each iteration of the loop

Comment: @Qirel yes, it is only for the question. Thank you both the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Change your function signature to take the value [*by reference*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php):**

```
function checkTranslation(&$foo) { /* ... */ }
```

**Why is that?**

When you pass something into a function, the value (a copy, so to speak) of that variable will be passed in. Whatever you do to it inside the function will not reflect to the original variable outside of that function.

However, if you add `&` in front of a parameter in the function signature, PHP will actually pass it in *by reference*, which means the function will operate on the very variable you passed in. Hence, any changes made within the function will be reflected outside, even once the function finishes.

If you are struggling with this concept, it can help to choose different names for the variable you pass in and the one in the method signature. This helped me with this issue when I started out:

```
function checkTranslation(&$input) { /* ... */ } // method
checkTranslation($foo);                          // using the method
```

**Alternatively...**

Just *return* `$foo` from your method, like so:

```
function checkTranslation($foo) {
    /* ... */
    return $foo;
}
```

And then, outside, something like:

```
$foo = checkTranslation($item['value'];);
```

**PS 1**

I'd recommend renaming the function so that is becomes more obvious what it does. `checkTranslation()` sounds like it would simply *check* if the input is valid and return a `boolean` or some other indicative value. However, you are actually (trying to) manipulate the input, so maybe something like `translate()` would be a better fit?

**PS 2**

Also note what *EatPeanutButter* pointed out in his comment: currently, you are overwriting `$foo` with every iteration of your loop. That doesn't seem to make a lot of sense.

Comment: Could possibly pass by reference in the loop, and use that value - because `$foo` inside the loop is still just a copy.

Comment: Thanks @domdom, didn't know about the value by reference. Also thank you for pointing out the naming. I'm changing the $foo each time becuase every new instance has a new value. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Its a bit hard to tell what's going on (and what should be done) without a little more context. Especially seeing how your `for` loop doesn't seem to be the actual loop you're having in your code, right? (`data` instead of `$data`, for example).

Comment: This code block is quite simple. I load the xml and then loop thro it to collect the values from the child nodes of each element. Every element has one node that has an attrbiute value which needs to be translated.

Comment: But how does that collecting of values work? Where do you store them?